# Why global list is automatically adds variables without explicit add statement?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, global-variables

I defined the visited_before list as a global list, but the issue is that; after making debugging, new variables are added implicitly to this list which made the whole code useless. If there is a possible tricky solution or tip I would be thankful to you.

Here is my code:

```
global visited_before



def give_next(initial):
    for block in initial:
        '''
        If block is empty move to the next block
        '''
        if not block:
            continue # change the block
        if block:
            packet = block[0]
            block.remove(packet)
        '''
        After this step, a disk is selected to be moved
        '''
        for position in initial:
            '''
        There are three cases:
        1. position is empty                        So add at index 0
        2. position is full with elements > packet  So add at index 0
        3. position is full with elements < packet  So Change the position   
            '''
            if block == position:
                continue # Don't return the disk to the first place !!
            elif not position:
                position.insert(0,packet)
            elif position[-1] > packet:
                position.insert(0,packet)
            elif position[-1] < packet:
                continue # Not allowed movment, SO change the block

            '''
            Check if the predicted step is in the visited_before list:
            if YES: change the block, in a try to predict a new step
            if  NO: add the step to the visited_before list and finish 
            '''
            if initial in visited_before:
                continue
            elif initial not in visited_before:
                visited_before.insert(-1, initial)
                print(initial)
                return initial


start_state = [[1,2,3],[],[]]
visited_before = [start_state]
give_next(start_state)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python objects are basically copied reference it not deeply copied. If you modify `start_state`, `visited_before` is also modified. (Actually, the latter just still points to modified `start_state`.)

If `start_state` is copied to `initial`, `initial` has elements pointing corresponding element of `start_state` because its elements are also Python objects, not primitives. If you modify `initial`'s element, you actually modify the corresponding element of `start_state`.

Thus, if you modify `position` which is an element of `initial`, you actually modify the corresponding element of `start_state` which is being pointed by `visited_before`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but is there a tricky way to avoid this action to be happening maybe using a different data structure?

Comment: @QaddomiObaid If you provide expected output, we could find the proper way.

Comment: My code tries to predict the next step of the Tower of Hanoi problem, and I need to ignore the steps which already predicted. So  if a= [[1,2,3],[],[]] was the input, the possible output could be [[2,3],[1],[]].... etc